# I can't see my model classes

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application in MVC4 with Razor and Entity Framework database first.I have a SQL database . Base on this I generated the diagram (edmx) with new Item "ADO.NET Entity Data Model".I choose the database connection,my tables and program has generated a diagram with tables and relationships but I can find the class that must be generated after each choosen table (in solution explorer .For a table student from database i must have the mapping with a class student in my solution ).I want to add some validations .Can somebody tell what I done wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EDMX diagram has a "code-behind" file. Click the > beside the .edmx file and you should see a file named the same as the .edmx but ending in .Designer.cs; the classes are defined in the "Entities" region in that file.

Having said that, you should never edit the contents of that file. The code in there is generated from your diagram, so any changes are lost when you alter the data model elsewhere. If you want to add validation attributes to your models, you'll need to create partial declarations somewhere else, and attach metadata classes to them. The accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059455/adding-validation-attributes-with-an-entity-framework-data-model) shows what you'll need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the namespace of the EDMX file , you can see that in the properties of the file.

Comment: I can't see the class in Solution Explorer.Let's say i have a table student in SQL and I will generate Ado.Net Entity data Model .After that the edmx diagram is created but i don't have a class with name student .

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you create EDMX file in folder Models.  in Solution Explorer -> Models -> Model1.edmx -> Model1.tt -> student.cs (this your  student table class)